# Network Load Balancing VMWARE

Tags: nlb

Is network load balancing (NLB) with windows server 2012 using unicast  and active-passive mode supported on  VMWARE ?

More details:

I have 3 http servers running inside a windows server 2012 network load balancer . They are routing the traffic to my application servers .If one server fails, the seconds will handle the requests. All this is implemented with physical servers in the datacenter .

Now i got a request to move to  Vmware in a way to have the same configuration as i explained.

I do not know if this will be possible .

Please read from the following  [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/274541/network-load-balancing-problem/275452#275452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you even bother doing a Google search?

The first result for `NLB VMware unicast` yields [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006778). It doesn't mention anything about active/passive, but since that's a function inside of NLB, it stands to reason that once you've got NLB setup, you can do whatever you want inside it.

Comment: I saw NLB VMware unicast on google . But was not sure if active/passive is possible . So i wanted to put all together in order to be more clear .